# how to display featured images of all posts in a single page of wordpress blog

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am making a WordPress theme and now I want to display featured images of every posts in a page called gallery and should be sorted according to the category of the posts.

Comment: Do you have gallery page already or need to create one? You can do a loop of posts using `get_posts` and the show featured image for post with `the_post_thumbnail`. There are plenty of articles already.

Comment: Please show what you have done so far and where it failed. Furthermore, you might want to read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please note also that this is not a free code writing service ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following code to your template file and change as per your needs.

```
<?php
//loop through category
$cat_args=array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$categories=get_categories($cat_args);
foreach($categories as $category) { 
    //loop through posts of category
    $args=array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'category__in' => array($category->term_id)
    );
    $posts=get_posts($args);
    if ($posts) {
        echo '<p>Category: <a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '">' . $category->name.'</a> </p> ';
        foreach($posts as $post) {
            setup_postdata($post);
            // if only featured image set
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('full'); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" /><br /><?php the_title(); ?></p>
            <?php
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will display only the featured images (which are referred to as the_post_thumbnail()):

```
    <?php 
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post(); 
        the_post_thumbnail();
    }  //end while
} //end if
?>
```